# Calling a Controller Method with parameters from a View when a button is clicked (cshtml, c#, MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, web-applications, asp.net-core

This is my Controller, where I would like to call the method AnswerASelect.

```
namespace VotingWebApp.Controllers
{
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {

    public async Task<IActionResult> Home()
    {
        return View(await _context.QuestionItem.ToListAsync());
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Answer(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var questionItem = await _context.QuestionItem.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
        if (questionItem == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(questionItem);
    }


    public async Task<IActionResult> AnswerASelect(int? id)
    {
        var questionItem = await _context.QuestionItem.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
        questionItem.AnswerAVote = questionItem.AnswerAVote + 1;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

This is my View where on the button click I would like to call the AnswerASelect method with the model as the parameter, something like... AnswerASelect(model)

```
@model VotingWebApp.Models.QuestionItem

 @{
  ViewData["Title"] = "Answer Question";
 }

 <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Question)</h2>


 <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick= "CALL AnswerASelect(Model)">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AnswerA)</button>
```

I was hoping to find a simple solution, thank you very much in advance. I'm new to Web App development and I am finding this difficult to learn. I have seen a few posts similar but I don't really have a good understanding of them, making it hard to apply the solution to my current problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect a user when a button is clicked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168577/how-do-i-redirect-a-user-when-a-button-is-clicked)

Comment: You would probably just need to make a form around N radio buttons, and set up some JavaScript to submit the form when one of them is selected.

Comment: Do you want to pass the Model to your Action via onclick (javascript) or i think you can pass it via form?

Comment: You can put everything inside form tag and post that content to action method " AnswerASelect", in that case our parameter inside that function should be of type model to map posted values to model object.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <h4 class="card-title addbutton">
        <button type="button" onclick="CreateModelDialog('@Url.Action("Create", "Controller",new {restaruntId =Model.RestaurantId})')" class="btn btn-info btn-rounded m-t-10  modal-link">Add</button>
    </h4>

  function CreateModelDialog(url) {
            debugger
            $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
            $('#modal-container').html("");
            $(".modal-backdrop").show();
            $(".stream-loader").show();
            $.get(url, function (data) {

                $(".stream-loader").hide();
                $('#modal-container').html("");
                $('#modal-container').html(data);
                debugger
                $('#modal-container').attr("style", "display:block !important");
            });
        }
```