# Trying to click a menu option and take me to a new view

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, view, onclick

Working in a MVC project using C# .Net.
I have a top menu where I have links to different views.
I'm trying to get my button click to take me to one of my views;

```
<input type="button" value="About Me" onclick="location.href='<%= @Url.Action("About Me", "AboutMePage") %>'"/>
```

But I'm hit with this error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<).

Not sure where I'm going wrong?

Cheers.

Comment: You are not doing it the MVC way. Your problem is that '<' is being taken literally, it's not being resolved.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168577/how-do-i-redirect-a-user-when-a-button-is-clicked

Comment: @PalleDue The only different I see is that they suggest window.location.href and a semi-colon at the end? Tried it and it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a Controller to Post your action.

```
<input type="submit" value="About Me"/>
```

After your controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

                return RedirectToAction("About Me", "AboutMePage");

        }
```